# Apiplatform Symfony App\Entity\collection does not exist

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I am working on a symfony 5.3 web dev project, everything works well with symfony until I use apiplatform 2.6 for the api.

When I try to access the api entrypoint in the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ I have the **ReflectionException Class App\Entity\collection does not exist** although the same link works well in postman (See output in the attached image) and I don't have any collection entity in my project. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

All my api calls work in postman, but not in the browser.
Thanks in advance for your comments.

[image]

**Code example for season class**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\SeasonRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SeasonRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"season:read"}},
 *      denormalizationContext={"groups"={"season:write"}}
 * )
 */
class Season
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("season:read")
     * @SerializedName("seasonDbId")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Groups("season:read")
     * @SerializedName("seasonName")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->name;
    }

}
```

Maybe the problem is there.
Collection from use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection; is the interface for App\Entity\Collection, but apiplatform seems not to be able to connect with it. I decided to try for testing only creating myself a Collection class in App\Enity\ to see the behavior. I have just created an empty class named Collection in \App\Entity, it worked, when I refreshed the page, same error appears. This is crazy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you forgot to import Collection with namespace in an Entity ?

If you use a Collection object but with no namespace, the default namespace is the current namespace. If your collection are call in App\Entity the default collection class became App\Entity\Collection.

Another probleme i could see is App\Entity\collection should be App\Entity\Collection with uppercase first char.

Are you using doctrine collection ? plateform api collection ?

Comment: I am using api platform. Without api platform access / ca// in the browser, my website works very well. I don't have any class named Collection nor collection. Collection is a reserved word in symfony, you can not use it as a class name. 

My suspicion is that apiplatform is somewhere trying to access or use \App\Entity\Collection or collection which does not exist in symfony.

So many people have encountered the same error, but with a different class name for each one. Example \App\Entity\DifferentClassName

Comment: Have you check this article ?
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28732
It could be the same erraor as you, it's probably not an API plateform bug but a symfony limitation, have you made any change in the api plateform context ?
Could you share your code ?

Comment: I will read carefully the link, thanks. I have just edited the question with code example of one of my classes. Note: when I run the project, everything works well. When I make API call in postman, everything works well, but when the api calls are made in the browser, I got the error.

Comment: Yes probably a template rendering object reflexion that does not work properly. Could you override the home template to check if this error persist ?

Comment: Collection from use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection; is the interface for App\Entity\Collection, but apiplatform seems not to be able to connect with it.

I decided to try creating myself a Collection class in App\Enity\ to see the behavior.
I have just created an empty class named Collection in \App\Entity, it worked, when I refreshed the page, same error appeared. This is crazy. I will edit the question to put the image related.

Comment: Yes i think it's like i said before, you have a class reflexion error create by a bundle or a template or an other element called on the template, because it work when api plateform send a jsonresponse.
Try to recreate a poc from scratch to recreate this bug and if it work try to merge the two projet.
Try to create an issue in apiplateform on github to see what append next

Comment: I have a live demo to do soon, but after I'll try to recreate a poc from scratch. For now, I have created an empty php file in \App\Entinty\ named **collection** not in capital letter and it works. I even cleaned the cache, warmed it up and it still works.

**\App\Entity\collection** is the solution for now. The file is empty, that's weird.